# Kubernetes fails to mount volumes inside WSL2 image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, docker-volume

I am attempting to setup a MSSQL-server in my WSL2 Linux distro, where I mount a volume for my `.mdf`- and `.ldf`-files.
However, I can't get Kubernetes to see my folder with said files.

I have my files stored in `C:\WindowsFolder\data` on my host (Windows), which allows WSL2 to see them at the path `/mnt/c/WindowsFolder/data` (Linux).

If I run the following yaml-file, `kubectl` sets up everything *but* my data - the folder I mount it into (`/data`) is empty.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-database
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: label-identifier
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: label-identifier
    spec:
      hostname: "database"
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 0
      containers:
        - name: database
          image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
          - containerPort: 1433
            protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: "ACCEPT_EULA"
              value: "Y"
            - name: "MSSQL_DATA_DIR"
              value: /data
            - name: "MSSQL_PID"
              value: "Developer"
            - name: "SA_PASSWORD"
              value: "SuperSecret123!"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: "myvolume"
              mountPath: /data

      volumes:
        - name: "myvolume"
          hostPath:
            path: "/mnt/c/windowsFolder/Database"
```

Then I tried to spin up a docker container inside my WSL2 - it works as expected, but this is not a good solution in the long run:

```
wsl.exe #Enter WSL2

docker run -d --name sql-t1 -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" \ 
  -e "SA_PASSWORD=SuperSecret123!" -p 1433:1433 \ 
  -v /mnt/c/windowsFolder/Database:/data \ 
  mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

docker ps #find my containerID

docker exec -it <containerId> bash #step into docker container

> ls /data #shows my files correctly
```

WSL2 can mount through docker correctly on the same path specified with Kubernetes, but it doesn't work from Kubernetes.

Any suggestions why, or what I might try?

**Edit 1:**

I did an `docker inspect <Kubectl's WSL container>` to see if it held any clues:

```json
[
  {
    "MountLabel": "",
    "HostConfig": {
      "Binds": [
        "/mnt/c/windowsFolder/Database:/data",
        ...
        ],
      },
      "VolumeDriver": "",
      "VolumesFrom": null,
      "Isolation": ""
    },
    "Mounts": [
      {
        "Type": "bind",
        "Source": "/mnt/c/windowsFolder/Database",
        "Destination": "/data",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": "rprivate"
      }
    ],
    "Config": {
      ...
      "Volumes": null,
      ...
    }
  }
]
```

**Edit 2:**

I noticed the folder has chmod of 755 instead of 777.
I fixed that by adding an `initContainer` and removing the security group, though it still did not help:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-database
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: label-identifier
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: label-identifier
    spec:
      hostname: "database"
      containers:
        - name: database
          image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
          - containerPort: 1433
            protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: "ACCEPT_EULA"
              value: "Y"
            - name: "MSSQL_DATA_DIR"
              value: /data
            - name: "MSSQL_PID"
              value: "Developer"
            - name: "SA_PASSWORD"
              value: "SuperSecret123!"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: "myvolume"
              mountPath: /data

      #this was added
      initContainers:
        - name: mssql-data-folder-permissions
          image: "busybox:latest"
          command: ["/bin/chmod","-R","777", "/data"]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: "myvolume"
              mountPath: /data

      volumes:
        - name: "myvolume"
          hostPath:
            path: "/mnt/c/windowsFolder/Database"
```

**Edit 3:**

On request of @ovidiu-buligan:

`kubectl get events -A` gives the following output:

```sh
NAMESPACE   LAST SEEN   TYPE     REASON              OBJECT                                     MESSAGE
default     2m15s       Normal   Scheduled           pod/myProject-database-7c477d65b8-mmh7h    Successfully assigned default/myProject-database-7c477d65b8-mmh7h to docker-desktop
default     2m16s       Normal   Pulling             pod/myProject-database-7c477d65b8-mmh7h    Pulling image "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
default     88s         Normal   Pulled              pod/myProject-database-7c477d65b8-mmh7h    Successfully pulled image "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest" in 47.2350549s
default     88s         Normal   Created             pod/myProject-database-7c477d65b8-mmh7h    Created container database
default     87s         Normal   Started             pod/myProject-database-7c477d65b8-mmh7h    Started container database
default     2m16s       Normal   SuccessfulCreate    replicaset/myProject-database-7c477d65b8   Created pod: myProject-database-7c477d65b8-mmh7h
default     2m16s       Normal   ScalingReplicaSet   deployment/myProject-database              Scaled up replica set myProject-database-7c477d65b8 to 1
```

`kubectl describe pod myProject-database-7c477d65b8-mmh7h` gives the following output:

```sh
Name:         myProject-database-7c477d65b8-mmh7h
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         docker-desktop/192.168.65.4
Start Time:   Tue, 06 Apr 2021 13:03:18 +0200
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/name=StatefulSet-database
              pod-template-hash=7c477d65b8
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.1.0.10
IPs:
  IP:           10.1.0.10
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/myProject-database-7c477d65b8
Containers:
  database:
    Container ID:   docker://f768710e7436d4c813913fa22a20091cb3fb77e1ecfbe2232b0ec6037eef3dbb
    Image:          mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server@sha256:ec5492b0b3f9c0707fddd37f0bd3d47d3ebea94a3054afb8b50e9e746d1e5f37
    Port:           1433/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 06 Apr 2021 13:04:07 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA:     Y
      MSSQL_DATA_DIR:  /data
      MSSQL_LOG_DIR:   /log
      MSSQL_PID:       Developer
      SA_PASSWORD:     SuperSecret123!
    Mounts:
      /data from storage-volume-claim (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-gcd5j (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  storage-volume-claim:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  database-pvc
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-gcd5j:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-gcd5j
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age    From               Message
  ----    ------     ----   ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  3m6s   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/myProject-database-7c477d65b8-mmh7h to docker-desktop
  Normal  Pulling    3m6s   kubelet            Pulling image "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
  Normal  Pulled     2m18s  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest" in 47.2350549s
  Normal  Created    2m18s  kubelet            Created container database
  Normal  Started    2m17s  kubelet            Started container database
```

Comment: what is the output of `kubectl get events -A`  (events dissapear after 30 mins )  ?. What is the output of `kubectl describe pod  mydatabase-99999` ?

Comment: @OvidiuBuligan - I can't see anything outstanding. Have a look at 'Edit 3' in the post.

Answer (score 3):

Solution found!

Docker Desktop created a folder to store everything in.

The following path in explorer, `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\kubelet\`, is equal to `/var/lib/` in a .yaml-file.

That means, you can write the following:

```yaml
...
  hostPath:
    path: "/var/lib/kubelet/myProject/"
    type: DirectoryOrCreate
...
```

This will give a folder in `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\kubelet\myProject`.
This will act as you want it to.

You might want to create a symlink with Windows Developer Mode to this place (Settings ->  Updates & Security -> For Developers -> Developer Mode).

Comment: could you provide a link where you found this information?